# Template non-type parameter minimum value

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to create class based on non-type parameters but they should be always greater than zero. The code:

```
template <int Row, int Columns>
class Workspace {
    static_assert(Row > 0 && Columns > 0);
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << Row * Columns;
    }
};
```

The code works well with static assert inside a class declaration. The question is: It is fine to do it this way and maybe is it better way to do it? The compiler I am using supports C++17 standard.

Comment: You might want to consider adding some error text (`static_assert(Row > 0 && Columns > 0, "Row and Columns must be greater than 0")` ), but otherwise yes this is legal code.

Comment: If you want it to be a hard error, then I can't think of a better way than a static assertion with a custom message.

Comment: If "they should be always greater or equals than zero" then you should probably use unsigned type instead of writing assertions.

Comment: @user7860670 That just hides bugs.  Using unsigned for values that can't be negative is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. They should be greater than zero :)

Comment: Anyhow, I think it is better to use `unsigned int` and not `int` in this case.

Comment: @user7860670 this won't prevent anybody from instantiating a template with parameters less then zero. But static assertion in that case will not find an error, since it will be a VERY BIG number.

Comment: @Mati you still can write `Workspace<-1, -1>()`, but there will be no error in this case. Guess why yourself.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik "you still can write Workspace<-1, -1>(), but there will be no error in this case" - you are completely wrong https://godbolt.org/z/XrR5Fi

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik it gives at least a warning if compiled using `-Wnarrowing`, you [can check it out](https://godbolt.org/z/yS-Hcs)

Comment: @user7860670 well, try again https://godbolt.org/z/qtkinc

Comment: @user7860670 Sure, the compiler catches that, but what about [this](https://godbolt.org/z/fNf7KH)?

Comment: @Kerek as NathanOliver said, it is an antipattern. You can look here https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#note-26

Comment: @NathanOliver So you wrote an implicit conversion from -1 to unsigned int getting a huge value and call use of unsigned an antipattern all of it sudden? That's a strong stance to take. Implicit conversion is an antipattern, uncontrollable over / under flow is an antipattern, but restricting the range of possible values that object can contain to only those values that make sense is certainly not.

Comment: @user7860670 Sure, the example is BS, but it is just an example and stuff like that happens all of the time.  Why make it difficult to find?  Even Bjarne has admitted that unsigned for size was a mistake.